# Swift background download task got suspended when I application goes into background

Tags: ios, swift, download, background

I am trying to create a download task that will continue to download a video even when the application is in the background.

So I followed the apple documentation to create a url session as background.
When I started the download process by tapped a button, I will print the progress of the download.
However, the application stops printing the progress when the application goes into background.

I wonder what did I miss, or misunderstand.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  private lazy var urlSession: URLSession = {
      let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "MySession")
      config.isDiscretionary = true
      config.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true
      return URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: 
      OperationQueue())
  }()
  var downloadUrl = "https://archive.rthk.hk/mp4/tv/2021/THKCCT2021M06000036.mp4"

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  @IBAction func downloadButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
      print("DownloadButton Tapped")
      let url = URL(string: downloadUrl)

      guard let url = url else {
         print("Invalid URL")
         return
      }

      let downloadTask = urlSession.downloadTask(with: url)
    
      downloadTask.resume()
  }
```

}

```
  extension ViewController: URLSessionDownloadDelegate, URLSessionDelegate {
        func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, 
           didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {
           print("Downloaded, location: \(location.path)")
        }

        func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, 
           didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, 
           totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {
           let progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
           print("Progress: \(progress)")
        }
 }
```

Comment: The download itself is not suspended, only your app is, this is why you don't see any logs being printed. When your application resumes, you can re-connect to that task and see the actual progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the background tasks to make that work properly.

For more details to configure background tasks please check this official apple developer documentation

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> However, the application stops printing the progress when the application goes into background.

Correct, your download progress updates will not be called when your app is suspended, as the data task has been handed off to an out-of-process daemon. But this is fine. When the user leaves your app, you really do not need/want the delegate methods being called. We want to minimize the drain on the users’ battery.

Note, the requests will proceed after your app has been suspended. They will even continue if the app is terminated in the course of its natural life cycle. (However, if the user force-quits your app, the associated background network request will not proceed.)

Obviously, when the download is done, your app will be awakened (in the background) to let you know that the download is done.

By the way, as noted in [Downloading Files in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background/), remember to:

- Implement `application(_:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:)` in your app delegate.
- Implement `urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession:)` in your `URLSessionDelegate`.